# How do I update an div css to display an complete image when section is complete?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

Using MVC 3

I have a questionaire that has three sections. The page that contains the questionaire has a "next","previous" and "save" button? When I click any of these buttons I want an ajax call to an Actioncontroller called "Question/SectionComplete" if it returns true I want to update menu div with the css that displays complete icon.
Can anyone help get started with sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onButtonClick(){
    var data = { myvar: 1 }; // your data to pass to action
    $.getJSON('Question/SectionComplete', data, function(result){
        if(result)
            $('#mymenudiv').css('background-image', 'yourImage'); //your styles here
    })
}
```

In controller:

```
public ActionResult SectionComplete(int myvar)
{
    // check condition
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet); // you can return complex object instead
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the success function of the .ajax method - documentation here - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/Question/SectionComplete',
  success: function(data) {
      // add code here
      // test for your response
      // then use jquery selector to get element to be updated
      // and use .html() to set element's new value
  }
});
```